# How to get all items into the Query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have 3 tables in my access database. One for products (tblProducts), one for purchases (tblPurchases), and one for orders (tblOrders).

```
tblProducts   tblPurchases    tblOrders

Name:         Name:  #Purc:   Name:  #Order:
Apple         Apple   5       Apple   2
Orange        Juice   6       Juice   3
Juice         Apple   5
Water         Juice   2
```

Now I am trying to make a query to have the net of all the products like this:

```
Name:    Net
Apple    8
Juice    5
Orange   0
Water    0
```

I have tried everything and nothing is working. I made a query to add up all the purchases but this happens:

```
Name:    Sum
Apple    10
Juice    8
```

Orange and water doesn't even show up as 0 which I think is the first problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: Please show the full schema for all 3 of your tables.

Comment: That is the full schema

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was make a query with just the names of products (qryList). After I did that, in a new query I used tblPurchases and qryList. This resulted in all the products showing up even if none were purchased.